# regular expression syntax for colon separators

Tags: regex

Given a string of

```
Customer Service Hours: am -
7 day/week
Prired
-AARPI MedicareComplete
watelnitedHealthcare
Health Plan (80840 911-87726-04
Member ID: QA00001-00
Group Number: 04535
Member
JOHN LINDIGO
Dental Benefits includos
Payer ID
РNorme
8176 Medicare R.
SMITH, MD JOHN
PCP Phone: (555) 123-2800
Nurse line:
1-877-365-7940
```

I'd like to capture the following

> ["Customer Service Hours", "Member ID", "Group Number", "PCP Phone", "Nurse line"]

My expression so far looks like

```
/\w+(?=:)/
```

Which returns

> ["Hours", "ID", "Number", "Phone", "line"]

How do I extend that capture group out to all the words inside the \n

Comment: You have no capturing group here. Use [`/\w[\w ]*(?=:)/`](https://regex101.com/r/H9Kan9/1)

Comment: that returns 
`["Customer Service Hours", "nMember ID", "nGroup Number", "nPCP Phone", "nNurse line"]`

Comment: It is because you are testing the regex against a string literal used as a literal string. Use it in the code where the string literal is parsed correctly with LF symbols specified with `\n`. What is the programming language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to capture all word characters/spaces (`[\w ]+`) from the start of the line (`^`) to just before the colon (`(?=:)`).

In multi-line mode, there will be a start of the line after every `\n`, so this will work with the "multi-line" and "global" flags:

```
^[\w ]+(?=:)
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It's showing me incorrect results in nodejs.

Comment: @ninesalt Hm, I don't think it should make a difference, but it doesn't say "node.js" in the OP's post. Also, yes, I've tried this. What's not correct?

Comment: That's perfect. Now how would I adjust that to capture what's AFTER the colon? I'm trying to create key/value pairs

Comment: You should get indexes with your matches (start/end or start/length, depending on what programming language you are using). You could write a loop over the matches to cut the other bits from the string, using some simple math from those indexes.